# how to replace elif statements and shorten code

Tags: python

here is my code at the moment, i was wondering if someone can help to shorten the code

```
def create_dice_dictionary(dice_list):
    
    dice_dictionary={1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0}
    
    for num in dice_list:
        
        if num==1:
            dice_dictionary[1]+=1
        
        elif num==2:
            dice_dictionary[2]+=1
     
        elif num==3:
            dice_dictionary[3]+=1
        
        elif num==4:
            dice_dictionary[4]+=1
       
        elif num==5:
            dice_dictionary[5]+=1
       
        elif num==6:
            dice_dictionary[6]+=1
    return dice_dictionary
```

Comment: You can also use [match case statement](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-switch-statement-switch-case-example/)

Comment: @CésarDebeunne, I thought of that as well, but it seems like a completely wrong approach for this problem. (Although I understand we all want to find a use for this new cool feature of Python 3.10 ;p)

Comment: Agreed, that's not a good usecase of match statements.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply your like this:

```
def create_dice_dictionary(dice_list):
    
    dice_dictionary={1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0}
    
    for num in dice_list:    
        dice_dictionary[num]+=1
        
    return dice_dictionary


res = create_dice_dictionary([1, 2, 3])
print (res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter:

```
def create_dice_dictionary(dice_list):
    dice_dictionary = {k:0 for k in range(1,7)}
    for d in dice_list:
        dice_dictionary[d] += 1
    return dice_dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter-based answer with filtering out values other than 1-6

```
from collections import Counter


def create_dice_dictionary(dice_list):
    d = [d for d in dice_list if d in range(1, 7)]
    return Counter(d)


dice_list = [1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 100, 5.5]

print(create_dice_dictionary(dice_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same output (assuming the input list only contains the values 1 to 6), you could use:

```py
import collections

def create_dice_dictionary(dice_list):
    d = {k: 0 for k in range(1, 7)}
    d.update(collections.Counter(dice_list))
    return d
```

But if the result does not **have** to be a dictionary, and you don't need the dices with count 0, you could just use `collections.Counter(dice_list)` instead.